# Cursor CSS interaction with Buttons

Tags: html, css, cursor

I'm trying to make a webpage with custom cursor, and it's working fine except when I mouse over buttons - how do I change this so that the custom cursor doesn't do this?

```css
body, html {
  cursor: url(cursor.gif), pointer;
}
```

```html
<body align="center">
  <h2>Click this button!</h2>
  <button onclick="location.href='/ever';">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for the question could be :

```
button {
    cursor: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
button {
    cursor: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser has some default styles for various elements. Default style for button has `cursor` set to `default`. As it is being more specific style, it takes the **precedence**. Hence, you need to override the same for it. You can try like following

```css
:hover {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
<button>test</button>
<input type="button" value ="Click"/>
```

**Note**, adding the `:hover` selector, will apply changes for every element. In case you have a different requirement, then you will have to specify the elements in the css accordingly.